# I have got an annoying celeryd worker restart issue with exitcode 1 or 15

Tags: python, redis, celery, restart, exit-code

I am using celery 3.0.21 with redis as backend, here is my celery config:

```
celery = Celery('cpps',
    broker='redis://127.0.0.1:6379/1',
    backend='redis://127.0.0.1:6379/1',
    include=['cpps.tasks'])

# Optional configuration, see the application user guide.
celery.conf.update(
    CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES=10800,
    CELERYD_FORCE_EXECV=True,
    BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {'visibility_timeout': 604800}, 
    # CELERYD_STATE_DB='cppsstate',
    default_exchange=Exchange('default', type='direct'),
    CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'default',
    CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE_TYPE = 'direct',
    CELERY_DEFAULT_ROUTING_KEY = 'default'
)
```

After execute a series of time consuming work for about twelve hours, I got exit with code 1,sometimes 15,as show below:

```
Restarting celeryd (cpps/celeryd.py worker -l debug -Q single_tasks --concurrency=1 -n single225)
[2013-12-03 09:15:43,535: DEBUG/MainProcess] Stopping celery.worker.consumer.Consumer...
[2013-12-03 09:15:43,536: DEBUG/MainProcess] consumer: Stopping consumers...
[2013-12-03 09:15:43,536: DEBUG/MainProcess] Stopping celery.worker.mediator.Mediator...
[2013-12-03 09:15:44,369: DEBUG/MainProcess] Stopping celery.concurrency.processes.TaskPool...
[2013-12-03 09:15:45,371: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'PoolWorker-255' pid:23832 exited with exitcode 1
[2013-12-03 09:15:51,379: DEBUG/MainProcess] Stopping celery.worker.hub.Hub...
[2013-12-03 09:15:51,379: DEBUG/MainProcess] consumer: Closing consumer channel...
[2013-12-03 09:15:51,379: DEBUG/MainProcess] consumer: Closing broadcast channel...
[2013-12-03 09:15:51,382: DEBUG/MainProcess] consumer: Closing broker connection...
Restoring 4 unacknowledged message(s).

 -------------- celery@single225 v3.0.21 (Chiastic Slide)
---- **** -----
--- * ***  * -- Linux-3.2.0-48-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-12.04-precise
-- * - **** ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> broker:      redis://192.168.11.226:6379/1
- ** ---------- .> app:         cpps:0x11d8b10
- ** ---------- .> concurrency: 1 (processes)
- *** --- * --- .> events:      OFF (enable -E to monitor this worker)
-- ******* ----
--- ***** ----- [queues]
 -------------- .> single_tasks: exchange:single(direct) binding:single
```

What is the problem?
What does the exitcode 1 exactly mean? I can't find official docs from  website.

Comment: Could you try a little bit more recent Celery - 4.2.1 for an example (not 4.3.0, it is buggy).